# Can you collapse commutativity of pseudo inverses with associativity?

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic, book-recommendation, semigroups

I've been studying the possibility of collapsing axioms and I'm stuck trying to prove something (by collapsing two axioms i mean find an axiom equivalent to them).

Take the following characterization (where the ' is the result of applying skolemization to the regularity of the semigroup):

$\begin{align} 
x(yz)&=(xy)z \tag{A1}\\
xx'x&=x \tag{A2}\\
xx'&=x'x \tag{A3}
\end{align}$

I've been trying to prove that (A3) and (A1) cannot be collapsed into a single identity (which I believe to be true since I haven't been able to collapse for a while now) but I'm having a hard time finding any literature on the subject.

So my question is: Do you know any book on the subject of the collapsing of axioms or know a proof of the impossibility of collapsing them (or an identity equivalent to both of them, if my statement is false)?

An example of an axiom that can be collapsed with associativity is $x''=x$.

One can prove that
$\begin{align} 
x(yz)&=(xy)z \tag{B1}\\
xx'x&=x \tag{B2}\\
x''&=x \tag{B3}\\
x'x&=xx' \tag{B4}
\end{align}$
Is equivalent to

$\begin{align} 
x(yz)''&=(xy)z \tag{E1}\\
xx'x&=x \tag{E2}\\
xx'&=x'x \tag{E3}\\
\end{align}$

What I've been trying to do thus far is to find two identities equivalent to (A1) and (A3) that have the same left (/right) member. So something of the sort:

$\begin{align} 
P&=Q\\
P&=R 
\end{align}$

I think (although I haven't seen a proof of it) that if such identities exist than you cannot collapse the two initial axioms.

Thanks in advance.

Ps: If you search for "On Single Equational-Axiom Systems for Abelian Groups" you find a proof that abelian groups are representable by a single identity.

Edit(15/03):
Is this argument valid?

Any identity expressing both associativity and comutativity of pseudo-inverses can't have x and x' together (like $\textbf{(xx')(yz) = ((xx')y)z}$ ), since one could make a non associative model where xx'=1, so the identity would be true.

Comment: I don't understand the parenthetical comment "where the ' is the result of applying skolemization to the axiom of regularity" - what do you mean by "axiom of regularity" here (presumably not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity))? (It looks to me like you just want $'$ to be the inverse.) Also, contra the title (A3) doesn't express commutativity (that would be "$xy=yx$").

Comment: Sorry you are right (I forgot regularity had another meaning). Yes I mean for ' to denote the pseudo inverse of x

Comment: The semigroups which satisfy your three axioms are called Clifford semigroups. These can be axiomatised with two axioms using the notion of "partial groups". I do not know if this is what you need, though, as these axioms are wholly different. What exactly do you mean by collapsing?

Comment: I mean find an axiom that is equivalent to those two. I thought a Clifford was an completely Regular Inverse Semigroup (so not really what i have)

Comment: A completely regular inverse semigroup is one in which every element commutes with its inverse. So this is precisely what you have.

Comment: But in an inverse semigroup the idempotents commute which is not the case here